# Smoothing the edges of an fbx file

Tags: modeling, edges, smooth

I want to import an fbx file and texture it, but when you have a closer look at the model you can see the single edges, even though I used auto smooth and applied shade smooth.
To use the subdivide modifier I would have to add some edge loops but that is more a workaround.

Does someone have a solution for the that? Or does it depend on the face count of the imported model only?

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: shade smooth will just affect the shading, it won't make the silhouette smoother. I don't think there's any other solution than subdividing your mesh (or giving it a Subdivision Surface modifier)

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course, if it's a low-poly model it would still appear jagged even after *Shade Smooth*!

An easy workaround to adding edge loops is adding a *Bevel Modifier* before the *Subdivision Surface Modifier* and playing with the bevel values.